# Remotely connect to MySQL using PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, css, phpmyadmin, xampp

My MySQL server is running on one PC(xampp).I want to insert data into the MySQL database(remote PC) using PHP script from another PC(client).I have made a website using HTML5 and CSS(client).As PHP runs on server,how do I connect to remote PC using a simple webpage?

Comment: I suggest you simply take a look into the documentation. All of phps mysql extensions and classes offer to directly connect to any mysql server accessible via network by simply configuring the correct network parameters. Take a look at the `mysqli` extension as an example: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php In addition you will find countless examples here on SO or out on the internet.

Comment: @arkascha in this case should I install xampp on both client and server?.Where should I run the .php which I created

Comment: Typically you have a system that executes php (often called the "server") and a system that accesses the php scripts via http (often called a "client", or a browser). You never implement a direct access from client to database. That would be a security and performance nightmare. You use the php scripts as central logic and gateway to communicate between client and database.

Comment: @arkascha....Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to a mysql database from anywhere using php. Just change the location to point to the remote server.

```
$servername = "ip_of_remote_server";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

But you have to configure the mysql server to allow remote connections if you are using the root user. See:
[How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)